# /etc/lsb-release vs /etc/os-release

Tags: linux, bash

I needed to find out what Linux distro I'm running by using bash. Found [this page](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-linux-distribution-name-version-number/), which was very helpful.

However my system has two /etc/*-release files

```
/etc/lsb-release
/etc/os-release
```

It seems `os-release` has a little more info, but it looks that both of these files essentially do the same thing. Does anyone know what is the difference between them? While we are at it, what does `lsb` in `lsb-release` stand for?

Comment: Linux Standard Base

Comment: @Pavel Do you know if there are non-standard bases? Also do you know what is meant by "Base" in Linux Standard Base?

Comment: It's a mess, really... Just check out https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/6345/how-can-i-get-distribution-name-and-version-number-in-a-simple-shell-script or https://superuser.com/questions/80251/how-to-know-which-linux-distribution-im-using

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on https://superuser.com OR https://unix.stackexchange.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here.Good Luck

Comment: @shellter Ok, will ask for the question to be moved. However I did not post the same question on 2 different sites. Did you see a similar question?

Comment: @flashburn : I'm just asking that you don't post this Q to another StackExchange forum and then leave this one in place, often known as cross-posting. Good luck!

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Also see [How can I reliably get the operating system's name?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/92199/56041) on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The `/etc/lsb-release` file is a file that some, but not all, Linux distributions put there for older programs to use. The "lsb" refers to the Linux Standard Base, a project working to define a common set of standards for any Linux distribution to follow, including things like filesystem layout. However, that file, `/etc/lsb-release`, isn't part of the standard. It's an extra thing that some distributions use, but not all.

The `/etc/os-release` file *is* the standard, however. Any distribution based on systemd, including Red Hat Enterprise Linux, CentOS, Fedora, Gentoo, Debian, Mint, Ubuntu, and many others, is required to have that file. Distributions that don't use systemd may also have the file.

If you need a reliable way of detecting what distribution you're running on, your best bet will be to read the /etc/os-release file. If it's not there you can try running the program called `lsb_release`. But just ignore the `/etc/lsb-release` file.

You can read more about os-release [here](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/os-release.html) and [here](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/os-release). And just for fun, take a look at [all the different files](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/release-files.html) that Linux distributions used to use!

Comment: The /etc/os-release was also adopted by FreeBSD.