# Dockerfile: How to set apt mirror based on the ubuntu release

Tags: docker, ubuntu, apt

While building a docker image, it's possible to set the custom apt mirror by overwriting the `/etc/apt/sources.list`, e.g.

```
FROM ubuntu:focal

RUN echo "deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal main restricted universe multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal-updates main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt focal-security main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
...
```

If the base image is a variable, e.g. `FROM ${DISTRO}`, the `sources.list` should be adjusted based on the ubuntu release.

I tried `$(lsb_release -cs)` like below:

```
RUN echo "deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt $(lsb_release -cs) main restricted universe multiverse" > /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt $(lsb_release -cs)-updates main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list && \
    echo "deb mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt $(lsb_release -cs)-security main restricted universe multiverse" >> /etc/apt/sources.list
```

But it says `lsb_release: not found`.

The workaround is to install the package before running it.

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y lsb-release
```

However, the install of `lsb-release` package could be very slow in some areas.

So the question is, is there a proper way to set the apt source mirror before using apt?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `lsb-release` package is not included in the minimal Ubuntu image, but you could make use of `/etc/lsb-release` or `/etc/os-release` file instead (the second one is in common use, refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53015255/7630831) for comparison).

For Dockerfile, just change `$(lsb_release -cs)` to `$(. /etc/os-release && echo $VERSION_CODENAME)`, you won't waste time in updating and installing packages.

Comment: Good suggestion! But when I try it in docker build, it results in `source: not found`. But it could be fixed by using `.. /etc/os-release && echo $VERSION_CODENAME`

Comment: updated, Dockerfile `RUN` uses `/bin/sh` by default instead of `/bin/bash`, `source` in bash is [an alias](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-source) for `.`, which is available in both bash and bourne shell.

Answer (score 11):

Just use [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html) to edit the existing `sources.list` files in-place.  The following snippet will modify the sources file in-place without regards to the exact distribution (and is safe to run on other Debian-based distributions, too, but will not modify the files there).

It changes all references to `http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu` to `mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt` (which tells the built-in `apt` client to automatically use a local mirror when fetching from the network) in `/etc/apt/sources.list`

```
sed -i -e 's/http:\/\/archive\.ubuntu\.com\/ubuntu\//mirror:\/\/mirrors\.ubuntu\.com\/mirrors\.txt/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

For use in a `Dockerfile`, simply `RUN` this - preferably as early in the `Dockerfile` as possible as so:

```
RUN sed -i -e 's/http:\/\/archive\.ubuntu\.com\/ubuntu\//mirror:\/\/mirrors\.ubuntu\.com\/mirrors\.txt/' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Comment: Please, explain more. Other people which want to use your solutions interest to read clear answers.

Comment: Quick hint: when you have slashes in the `sed` string, you can avoid the "leaning toothpick syndrome" by choosing a different separator. Something like `sed -i -e 's#http://...#...#`  would make the command much easier to read (and write)

Answer (score 0):

In the dockerfile reflect the `.. /etc/os-release && echo $VERSION_CODENAME` for the `lsb-release`