# DOCKER VSCODE devcontainer.json mount local source to image target

Tags: docker, mount, vscode-devcontainer

## devcontainer: Failed Mounting local target to container

I am having trouble mounting my dataset folder in a Docker container for machine learning. The folder is quite large, so I want to avoid copying it within the Dockerfile. I am able to successfully mount the directory using `docker run -it --gpus all --volume D:/tmp/test:/app/data open3d:gpu` command, but when I try to transfer this configuration to VSCodes dev container environment by changing the `devcontainer.json`, it fails to mount.

I followed [the official example from VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/remote/advancedcontainers/add-local-file-mount), but even though building the container works fine and VSCode can open the project in the container, the `target` folder is not created and nothing gets mounted. Can anyone help me troubleshoot this issue?

### Setup Info:

> VScode version: 1.77.3
> Windows 10 -> Docker Desktop
> Docker version: 20.10.24

### Docker File:

```
# This could also be another Ubuntu or Debian based distribution
FROM nvidia/cuda:11.7.0-cudnn8-devel-ubuntu22.04

# 
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./requirements.txt .
COPY ./requirements-torch.txt .


# automatically use a local mirror when fetching from the network
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62034545/dockerfile-how-to-set-apt-mirror-based-on-the-ubuntu-release
RUN sed -i -e 's/http:\/\/archive\.ubuntu\.com\/ubuntu\//mirror:\/\/mirrors\.ubuntu\.com\/mirrors\.txt/' /etc/apt/sources.list  

RUN apt-get -y update
# RUN apt-get --allow-releaseinfo-change -y update
RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y libegl1 libgl1 libgomp1

# Install Python and pip
RUN apt-get install --no-install-recommends -y \
    python3-pip \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    install nvidia-container-runtime

# Install Open3D from the PyPI repositories
RUN --mount=type=cache,target=/root/.cache \
    python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip && \
    python3 -m pip install --upgrade open3d


# Install requirements
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
# Install PyTorch with dependencies
RUN python3 -m pip install -r requirements-torch.txt


COPY ./app /app
COPY ./tests /tests
```

### devcontainer.json file:

```
// For format details, see https://aka.ms/devcontainer.json. For config options, see the
// README at: https://github.com/devcontainers/templates/tree/main/src/docker-existing-dockerfile
{
    "name": "open3D-ml",
    "build": {
        // Sets the run context to one level up instead of the .devcontainer folder.
        "context": "..",
        // Update the 'dockerFile' property if you aren't using the standard 'Dockerfile' filename.
        "dockerfile": "../Dockerfile"
    },
    "runArgs": [
        "--gpus",
        "all"
    ],
    "mounts": [{
        "type": "bind",
        "source": "D:/tmp/test",
        "target": "/home/app/data"
    }],
    "customizations": {
        "vscode": {
            "extensions": [
                "ms-python.python"
            ]
        }
    }
```

## Troubleshooting:

Googleling only revealed that there was a problem with other VScode versions, but this bug should be removed with version > 1.41+, and of course I tried to rebuild the devcontaienr multiple times as mentioned in some posts.

#### configurations i tried:

devcontainer.json

```
    "mounts": [{
        "type": "bind",
        "source": "D:/tmp/test",
        "target": "/home/app/data"
    }],
```

devcontainer.json

```
"mounts": [
  "source=D:/tmp/test,target=/home/app/data,type=bind,consistency=cached"
]
```

devcontainer.json

```
    "runArgs": [
        "--gpus",
        "all",
        "--volume",
        "D:/tmp/test:/home/app/data"
    ],
```

None of their versions link mount my source folder....

Comment: I am having the same problem at the moment. Since you can mount the dir using docker run, would you be able to replicate that using runArgs instead of mounts in the devcontainer?

Comment: No, like I tried to show with the part

``` 
    "runArgs": [
        "--gpus",
        "all",
        "--volume",
        "D:/tmp/test:/home/app/data"
    ],
```

passing the volume to the runArgs dose not work from the devcontainer.json and not with VSCode. 
It only works if I run the container directly from the console. 

For now, I circumnavigate the problem by creating an extra docker volume. This way I copy the dataset only one time and can use the datasets in all docker containers ... 
Drawback, i cannot access the data from windows.

Comment: Ah sorry, I see that now. The workaround I'm using is to map the directory with my files as a Windows drive, then mount it in WSL2, and then specify the WSL2 location as the mount source in devcontainer.json. It ok for now, but I'm sure there must be a better way.